# Type already defines a member with the same parameter types

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an error saying:

Type 'GameManager' already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types

[Error message in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cWNl.png)

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgKhU.png)

Comment: Can you post some code?  In the meantime, my guess is that you are treating `selectedZombine` as a method as the error says (you are doing `selectedZombie()` somewhere) and the other error means you are referencing `selectedZombie` without declaring what it is.

Comment: Paste you code as text, not an image, also that doesn't come off as friendly by the way.

Comment: You misspelled `selectedZombie ` as `slectedZombie`

Comment: Also, `slectedZombie(zombies[3])` is wrong because `slectedZombie` is not a method

Comment: so what do I put instead ?

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `SelectZombie` instead

Comment: na it still say it

Comment: You have it in 2 places

Comment: but the video tell me to do that

Comment: i don't know what video you're watching, but `selectedZombie(zombies[3])` will not work because `selectedZombie` is not a function, it is a GameObject.  `SelectZombie(zombies[3])` will work because `SelectZombie` is a function that takes in a GameObject.

Comment: can you please tell me what do I need  to put instead please ?

Comment: ??? I just did, replace `selectedZombie(` with `SelectZombie(`

Comment: look i will send a norther photo m8

Comment: `SelectZombie(zombies[3]);` and `SelectZombies(zombies[0]);`

Comment: Please put the code as text in the body of the question instead of as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. like others said what you're trying is using GameObject like a method.
And it's not gonna work that way.

The Error you're getting now is caused by duplicated Update().
Try Change first Update() to Start()
Edited my codes below.

try below codes

```
void Start()
{
    SelectZombie(selectedZombie);
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
    {
        GetZombieLeft();
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("Right"))
    {
        GetZombieRight();
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("up")){
    }
}

void GetZombieLeft()
{
    if (selectedZombiePosition == 0)
    {
        SelectZombie(zombies[3]);
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject newZombie = zombies[selectedZombiePosition - 1];
        SelectZombie(newZombie);
    }
}

void GetZombieRight()
{
    if (selectedZombiePosition == 3)
    {
        SelectZombie(zombies[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        SelectZombie(zombies[selectedZombiePosition + 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @NUGGET You have 2 Update methods and that's why that error pops up.

Comment: @NUGGET change first Update method (which contains SelectZombie(selectedZombie);) to Start method or merge those Update methods into ONE.

Comment: @NUGGET Edited my answer. Try them and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this:

```
void Update() {
    ...
}

void Update() {
    ...
}
```

You can only have one `Update()` definition. They should be merged into one.